# Don't allow a user account to modify or logout an app

Tags: windows-10, parental-controls

I have a Windows 10 with two user accounts: Dad and Daughter. Dad account is an administrator local account. Daughter account is a simple local account.

With Dad account I have installed a "Freedom.to" app as a parental control app. However, when Daughter account starts Windows 10, Daughter account can access, modify or quit the parental control app.

As you can see in this picture, I need that parental control app may start when Windows 10 starts, but Daughter account shouldn't have any right to quit or change any configuration of that parental control app.

How can I setup that configuration for Daughter account in Windows 10?

[image: Daughter account when right-click butterfly icon]

Comment: What does the documentation for the application indicate?  There must be a step in the installation process where you assigned if a Windows account is a managed user account or an unmanaged administrator user account.  The option should be in Options more than likely.  It seems like you have skipped several steps.

Comment: Why are you using a third-party product when Windows 10 has the best built-in parental control and monitoring around. See [What is a Microsoft family group?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/what-is-a-microsoft-family-group-b6280c9d-38d7-82ff-0e4f-a6cb7e659344) and also [How to Use the Parental Controls in Windows 10?](https://famisafe.wondershare.com/parental-control/windows-10-parental-controls.html).